# Prove that $|z_{n}|\to \infty$ iff $\frac{1}{z_{n}}\to 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_{n}$ be a sequence of complex numbers.

Prove that  $|z_{n}|\to \infty$ iff $\frac{1}{z_{n}}\to 0$.

Comment: $|z_n|>K\iff \dfrac{1}{|z_n|}<\dfrac{1}{K}$

Comment: would that be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the fact
$$z\to0\iff |z|\to0$$

**Edit**

If $|z_n|\to\infty$ so for all $A>0$ there's $N$ such that $|z_n|>A$, $\forall n\ge N$ and this is equivalent to $\frac 1{|z_n|}<\frac1A, \forall n\ge N$ which means  that $\frac 1{|z_n|}\to0$ and then $\frac 1{z_n}\to0$ using the hint.

Comment: can you say a little more?

Comment: @hu123 I said little more;-)